# When .. elsewhen equations seems to be reversed in Wolfram Systemmodeler

Tags: modelica, .when, systemmodeler

When I try this simple modelica code in Wolfram Systemmodeler:

```
model bug
  Integer y(start = 1);
equation
  when time > 0.2 then
    y = 5 "y = 2";
  elsewhen time > 0.4 then
    y = 4 "y = 3";
  elsewhen time > 0.6 then
    y = 3 "y = 4";
  elsewhen time > 0.8 then
    y = 2 "y = 5";
  end when;
end bug;
```

the result is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, like this: [Model bug simulatiom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0jy0.jpg). The when-equations seems to be activated in the reverse order.

On the othe hand, changing "equation" to "algorithm", and (of course) "=" to ":=" the code turns:

```
model nobug
  Integer y(start = 1);
algorithm
  when time > 0.2 then
    y := 5;
  elsewhen time > 0.4 then
    y := 4;
  elsewhen time > 0.6 then
    y := 3;
  elsewhen time > 0.8 then
    y := 2;
  end when;
end nobug;
```

and the result is as expected, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, like this: [Model nobug simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzYQZ.jpg)

Is this a relatively *basic* problem in the Wolfram SystemModeler implementation, or there is something else I cannot see?

Comment: There's an issue with how SystemModeler handles the `bug` model. It will be fixed in a future version.